# Can't import class model in database SQLAlchemy from shell python

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

My problem is that I have no possibility adding users by python shell. Then I add users if I import class Admin from application but I got error
`NameError: name 'Admin' is not defined`.

in models.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer, ForeignKey, DateTime
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

class Admin (db.Model):
    idAdmin = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    login = db.Column(db.String(255))
    password = db.Column(db.String(255))
    pin = db.Column(db.Integer)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255))
    surname = db.Column(db.String(255))

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Admin('{self.name}','{self.surname}')"
```

in **init**.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from model import db
from flask_wtf.csrf import CSRFProtect
import os

app = Flask(__name__)

file_path = os.path.abspath(os.getcwd()) + "\database.db"
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "sqlite:///" + file_path

db = SQLAlchemy()
db.create_all()
```

folder

```
aplication
|
|-----app
|     |
|     |---static
|     |   |...      
|     |
|     |---templates
|     |   |...
|     |
|     |---__init__.py
|     |
|     |---forms.py
|     |
|     |---models.py
|     |
|     |---views.py
|
|-----run-test.py
|
|-----run.py
|
|-----start.sh
```

According to https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/quickstart/
I must consider:

1. `>>> from app import db`
2. `>>> db.create_all()`
3. `>>> from app import Admin`
4. `>>> admin = Admin(username='John', password='1qaz@WSX', pin='1234', name='John', surname='Trump')`
5. `>>> db.session.add(admin)`
6. `>>> db.session.commit()`

After entering the command `>>> admin = Admin(username='John', password='1qaz@WSX', pin='1234', name='John', surname='Trump')` 
I get error `NameError: name 'Admin' is not defined`

Comment: What is going on with `from model import db` in `__init__.py`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your import should be

```
from app.models import Admin
```